# spring security @Secured and HttpSession config ordering

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I am using `Spring Security` (3.2.5.RELEASE). I try to achieve below scenario:

1. I have two kind of users in my application: regular user and admin
2. I want to use `@Secured` annotation on controller methods (annotated with `@RequestMapping`)
3. Methods which are not annotated with `@Secured` I want to be accessible for all (even anonymous users).
4. Methods which are annotated with `@Secured` are permited for regular users if they have specific role passed to `@Secured` annotation. These methods should be also always permited for admin users but I don't want to put `ROLE_ADMIN` on every time when I use `@Secured` annotation.

This is my HttpSession configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .permitAll()
     [...] 
    }
```

I can annotate my controller methods with `@Secured` annotation and it works. The only problem is how I can add url-intercept matcher for permitting all users which has role `ROLE_ADMIN` before access rules collected from `@Secured` annotatated methods. For now it looks like `@Secured` methods are first in filter chain and rules added to `HttpSession` in code above are last. How can I add rule that will be first (for `ROLE_ADMIN` permision) and last (for all methods not annotated with `@Secured` permision), and all rules from `@Secured` annotations will be wrapped by these two rules? To be more clear, I want to achieve something like this (in chain):

```
1) allow all for users with ROLE_ADMIN
2) all rules from @Secured
3) allow methods not annotated with @Secured for all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've achieved that but not exactly like in question. This is what I've done:

1. Create own `AccessDecisionVoter` which will always return `ACCESS_GRANTED` for user which is admin.
2. Override default `AccessDecisionManager`s creation: both!!! One for url intercepting and one for method intercepting.

This is my `AdminPermitVoter`

```
public class AdminPermitVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
        if(isAdmin(extractAuthorities(authentication))) {
            return ACCESS_GRANTED;
        }
        return ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Authentication authentication) {
        return authentication.getAuthorities();
    }

    private boolean isAdmin(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        for(GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
            if(equalsIgnoreCase(ADMIN_ROLE_NAME, authority.getAuthority())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This is creation of default url interecption access decision manager:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
        [...other configs...]
 }

@Bean(name = "accessDecisionManager")
public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
    List<AccessDecisionVoter> voters = new ArrayList<>();
    voters.add(new AdminPermitVoter());
    voters.add(new WebExpressionVoter());
    voters.add(new RoleVoter());
    voters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());
    return new AffirmativeBased(voters);
}
```

This is creation of default method interception access decision manager:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter> voters = new ArrayList<>();
        voters.add(new AdminPermitVoter());
        voters.add(new RoleVoter());
        voters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());
        return new AffirmativeBased(voters);
    }

}
```